# Proof of a simple relation of $1-\mathrm{exp}(ix)$

Tags: trigonometry

I read an calculating $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \sin(kx)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \cos(kx)$. I already know this calculation by multiplying $\sin(x/2)$ and using telescoping sum. However the calculation I read recently shows that we can calculate it by de Moivre.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n \cos(kx) + i \sin(kx)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n e^{ikx}\\
&=\frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{inx})}{1-e^{ix}}
\end{align}

Now what I have a trouble understanding this calculate came here. The author wrote that

\begin{align}
1-e^{ix} &= (1-\cos x) - i \sin x\\
&=2\sin^2(x/2) - 2i \sin (x/2) \cos (x/2) \\
&=2\sin(x/2)(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2}) + i \sin (\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2}))\\
&= 2\sin(x/2) e^{(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2})}
\end{align}

It is weird to me. I think it is not $2\sin(x/2) e^{(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2})}$ but $-2\sin(x/2) e^{(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2})}$. It must have $(-1)$ factor. It is trivial to yours but whenever the author using this $1-e^{ix}$, he always omit $(-1)$. Am I right that it should have $(-1)$ factor?

Comment: Yeah, there should be a $(-1)$ factor in the expression and instead of $e^{(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2})}$ it should be $e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{x}{2})}$

Comment: Are you sure that the lower index is $k=0$? The geometric sum formula is for lower index $k=1$, else it would have to be $\dfrac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}$.

Comment: For small $x$ the expression has a negative imaginary part, so yes the written identity is wrong.

Comment: Or set $n=0$ to get the contradiction in $1=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter, using complex arithmetic instead of trigonometric identities:
\begin{align}
1-e^{ix}
&=e^{ix/2}\,(e^{-ix/2}-e^{ix/2})
\\
&=-2i\,e^{ix/2}\sin(x/2)
\\
&=2\,e^{i(x/2-\pi/2)}\sin(x/2)
\end{align}

---

This kind of reasoning applied to the full fraction of the geometric sum gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^ne^{ikx}=
 \frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{inx})}{1-e^{ix}}&=\frac{e^{ix}e^{inx/2}(e^{inx/2}-e^{-inx/2})}{e^{ix/2}(e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2})}
\\[.5em]
&=e^{i(n+1)x/2}\,\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{\sin x/2}
\end{align}